# trying to find the general term for a serie in an easy way

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have a general expression which is the following:
$$b_0=7$$
$$b_n = 2b_{n−1}+7\cdot4^n\quad∀n∈\Bbb N^+$$
and that I have to it resolve in the easiest way possible. I know that I could use the generative function technique, but there is probably quicker ways.

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Observe that
$$
\frac{b_{n}}{2^n}- \frac{b_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}} = 7 \cdot 2^{n}
$$ then by summing terms telescope on the left hand side, the sum on the right hand side being easy to evaluate, you get
$$
\frac{b_{N}}{2^N}- \frac{b_{0}}{2^{0}}=7\sum_{n=1}^N 2^{n}, \qquad N=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$b_n = 2b_{n−1}+7\cdot4^n=2(2b_{n−2}+7\cdot4^{n-1})+7\cdot4^n=2^2b_{n-2}+2\cdot7\cdot4^{n-1}+7\cdot4^n$. Repeating this we get $$b_n=2^nb_0+7\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n2^{n-k}4^k$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to look at this. Consider the general form

$$f_n=A\cdot B^n+Cf_{n-1}$$

Then we can write

$$\frac{f_n-Cf_{n-1}}{f_{n-1}-Cf_{n-2}}=\frac{A\cdot B^n}{A\cdot B^{n-1}}=B\\
$$
or
$$
f_n=af_{n-1}+bf_{n-2}\\
$$
where
$$
a=B+C\\
b=-B
$$

This is now in a familiar form for which we know the characteristic roots

$$\alpha,\beta=\frac{a\pm \sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}$$

And we'll also need $f_1=A\cdot B+ Cf_0$ to complete the solution.